# How do I get an application's performance data on Windows using C#?

Tags: c#, testing, automation, performance-testing

I am new to test automation and falls into an automation project using C # where the objective is to obtain performance data during the processing of an application, but I have no idea how to do this.

I thought about getting this data through the Windows Performance Monitor but I also have no idea how to get this data from there.

Would anyone have another idea or does anyone know how I get this data from Windows Performance Monitor?

The data I need to obtain is the CPU consumption and the RAM memory consumption.

The time the application is being processed is not accurate. There are times when the application takes 10 seconds, 30 seconds, 50 seconds ..., depending on the size of the input file. What I have in mind is to create an automation to obtain the data of CPU consumption and RAM memory consumption during this processing so as not to have to get this information manually.

The application is local, desktop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First question: What performance data do you need? How much memory the application uses? How long it runs for a particular job? How much data it transfers over the network? The answer will depend on that.

Comment: Some rough performance data, such as the memory used, can be obtained using Windows Performance Monitor. More accurate results (especially about which parts of the code use most of the CPU time) can be found by using profilers. The "standard solution" is to use JetBrains dotTrace. The application can be downloaded and tested for free.